# iOS app sending an alert view only on the first time using the app

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I would like to display an alertview when a user opens the app for the first time. After they open the app, they click on a button that pushes a table view on the navigation controller stack. If it's the first time the table view has ever been opened, there should be an alert view that displays telling the user that they can click the cell to edit.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply, use `NSUserDefaults`.

something like:

```
// the place where you want to check if this is the first run:
BOOL didRunBefore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"didRunBefore"];

if (!didRunBefore) {
    // show alert;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"didRunBefore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Oops, I set it the other way around. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

When your user taps on your button you should check for some value in `[NSUserDefaults standardDefatults]` if the check is nil you should display your alert and then save some value, so the next time you check for it, it would have some value stored and you do nothing.

Like this:

```
NSString * val = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kFirstTime"];
if (!val) {

    //show alert
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"kFirstTime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

//Your code
```